# checking a color of a button and changing it using a 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a small game just like the game Reversi/Othello I have managed to created a 2x3 board with buttons.

The buttons change colour ones you click on them but I'm having trouble to detect if there is a white colour in between 2 black colours and if so change that white colour into black.. I hope this make sense. the buttons are in a 2D array. Any suggestions that could help me do this would be much appreciated.

The image:

[image]
Here is my code:

```
![namespace reversitest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Button\[,\] squares;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            squares = new Button\[3, 2\];
            squares = new Button\[,\] {{button1,  button2,  button3},
                {button4,  button5,  button6,}};
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (Button sqrr in squares)
            {
                sqrr.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.DrawCharacter);
            }
        }
        int _turn = 0;
        private void DrawCharacter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button sqrr = (Button)sender;
            int col = 0;

            if (sqrr.BackColor.Equals(Color.Black) || sqrr.BackColor.Equals(Color.White))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Move Not Allowed!");
            }
            else 
            {
               for ( int i = 0; i < squares.GetLongLength(1); ++i)
               {

                  // check othere squares and change color
                   if (i < 2)
                   {
                       for (int f = 0; f < 3; ++f)
                       {
                           var ss = squares\[i, f\];
                           if (ss.BackColor.Equals(Color.Black))
                           {

                               MessageBox.Show("we have a black");

                               //ss = squares\[i, f+1\];
                               ss.BackColor = Color.Black;

                           }
                           else
                           {
                               MessageBox.Show("no black");
                           } 
                       }

                   }

                       if (_turn == 0)
                       {
                           _turn = 1;
                           sqrr.BackColor = Color.Black;


                       }
                       else
                       {
                           _turn = 0;
                           sqrr.BackColor = Color.White;


                       } 

               }


            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that board size going to be fixed (2x3) or vary?

Comment: @NewDeveloper It will grow to a 8x8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First name your buttons with the array index. It will help you to find the button.
For example according to you picture button1 name would be btn_1_1.

Then inside your button click event first get the button name and then identify the button positioned.

```
        Button b = sender as Button;
        string[] btnData = b.Name.Split('_');
        int x = int.Parse(btnData[1]);
        int y = int.Parse(btnData[2]);

        //check for possible combinations 
        int top = y - 2;
        int botton = y + 2;

        int left = x - 2;
        int right = x + 2;

        if (top >= 0 && squares[top, y].Background == Color.Black)
        {
            squares[top+1, y].Background = Color.Black;
        }  
        ...  
        ...
```

Continue like that. If you need more detail please free to ask.

Comment: will i need to replace my code in the click event with this code? p.s I really appreciate your answer

Comment: The if statement seems to have to many errors mainly with .Background as it should be .BackColor (squares[top+1, y].BackColor == Color.Black; seems to give me a problem it says "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement and new object expressions can be used as a statement")

Comment: Sorry. There is an typo error in my code **quares[top+1, y].Background == Color.Black;** should be corrected as **quares[top+1, y].Background = Color.Black;**

Comment: Isn't that the same? im trying this: squares[top + 1, y].BackColor== Color.Black; but still same problem

Comment: You are referring to line which is execute when **if** becomes true. Am I correct? It has two equal signs which should be corrected to on sign. I have edit the error in my code.

Comment: Now it says for: int x = int.Parse(btnData[1]); "Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22140/discussion-between-new-developer-and-tacit)

Answer (score 1):

Final Answer

```
//check for possible combinations 
            int top = x - 2;
            int botton = x + 2;

            int left = y - 2;
            int right = y + 2;

            if (top >= 0 && squares[top, y].BackColor == Color.Black)
            {
                squares[top + 1, y].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
            else if (left >= 0 && squares[x, left].BackColor == Color.Black)
            {
                squares[x, left + 1].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }

            else if (left >= 0 && squares[x, left].BackColor == Color.Black)
            {
                squares[x, left + 1].BackColor = Color.Black;
            }
```

Will be extended for a 8x8 board later on

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to be elegant? A kind of brute force method: You could check for pieces in the 8 different directions it is possible for them to be aligned. So for example, you start with a black piece. Check the next piece over in one direction. If it's white, keep going and take a note of the position that was white so you can change it to black later. When you finally hit a black piece, change all the stored positions to black and move on to the next direction and repeat the process until you've done all 8 directions.